# Simple Travis-CI BUILD gives "no environment variables set"

Tags: python, travis-ci

I am trying to build with travis for the first time.  I thought my `.travis.yml` was simple enough.

Here is my .travis.yml

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - pip install .
# command to run tests
script:
 - pytest
```

The build seems to have no problems but surprisingly the travis interface shows failed with "no environment variables set":

[build failed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQGvd.png)

(link to travis build):
https://travis-ci.org/DataReply/persistable/builds/449064588

I cannot understand from the documentation or find hints online about why this happens so I've resorted to asking here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click a build job to see the full console output. You'll notice that your build fails because there are no tests defined (and in that case pytest exits with a non-zero exit code: `The command "pytest" exited with 5.`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick look and feedback.  I guessed it would be something small.